# Jenkins configuring jobs for the latest revision

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm trying to configure job in Jenkins, I have different revisions for project in svn and my Jenkins job should checkout the latest revision and start build. Is there any way to do this ? Ps. my Jenkins works on fedora thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you well. The natural behavior is to run build each time a new revision pops into svn (scm in general). You can simply add new job to your Jenkins dashboard. Then there is option to checkout project from local repository (Source Code Management tab). Check the Subversion and input repository URL. In build triggers tab select Poll SCM, choose how often and then it should be ready to build after each commit.

Comment: yes normally I do that, but the problem is there will be no specif folder every time to take build, for example for the project A, there are versions and their folders like 1.1,1.2,1.3...1.9. My jenkins should build version 1.9 which is latest.